# gmailapp.sendemail outgoing mail gets blocked when send to a gmail account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-forms

First off I am not an IT wizard, I am ok at using other people code. So ... please keep it simple, perhaps use crayons when explaining it to me.

I've made an online questionnaire that auto-sends the report as a pdf attachment to the participant, using google forms + google sheets + apps script (source of inspiration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpZGvKIHmR8).

It works great, except if the user has a gmail account. Rather than sending the email to participant I get an auto reply that the message may contain a virus.

My code:

```
  function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
  const wsData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  const wsResponses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");

  const score = CalculateScores(wsResponses, wsData, entryRow);
  
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info, score);
 
  sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email address'][0], pdfFile);  
}


function sendEmail(email, pdfFile){

GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Morningness - Eveningness Questionnaire Report", "You receive this email as you recently filled in the Morningness - Eveningness Questionnaire. Your report PDF is attached." + "\n\n" + "Kind regards,"+ "\n\n" + "ID", {
  attachments: [pdfFile],
  name: 'Website - Tools',
  replyTo: "my.personal.email.but.not.this.one@gmail.com"  
});
}


function createPDF(info, score) {

const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("... Google ID ...");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("... Google ID ...");
const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("... Google ID ...");

const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
const body = openDoc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{Score}", score);

if (score <= 30) {
  // a Lark
  // a morning person
  body.replaceText("{Type}", "an evening person or a Owl");  
} else if (score > 69) {
  // an Owl
  // an evening person
  body.replaceText("{Type}", "a morning person or a Lark");
} else if (score > 30 && score < 42) {
  // an 3rd bird
  // an Moderate evening person
  body.replaceText("{Type}", "a moderate evening person or an Owl");
} else if (score > 58 && score < 70) {
  // an 3rd bird
  // an Moderate evening person
  body.replaceText("{Type}", "a moderate morning person or a Lark");
} else {
  // a 3rd bird
  // an intermediate person
  body.replaceText("{Type}", "an intermediate person or a 3rd bird");
};


openDoc.saveAndClose();


const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Email address'][0] + " " + new Date());
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);

return pdfFile;

}


function CalculateScores(wsResponses, wsData, LastRow) {
  
  
  wsData.getRange(LastRow, 1).setValue(wsResponses.getRange(LastRow,1).getValues()[0]);
  wsData.getRange(LastRow, 2).setValue(wsResponses.getRange(LastRow,2).getValues()[0]);
  
  //Q1
  var labels = wsResponses.getRange(LastRow,3).getValues()[0];
  labels.forEach(function(label){
    switch(label) {    
      case "5h00 – 6h30":
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 3).setValue(5);
        break;    
      case "6h30 – 7h45":
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 3).setValue(4);
        break;
      case "7h45 – 9h45":
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 3).setValue(3);
        break;
      case "9h45 – 11h00":
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 3).setValue(1);
        break; 
      case "11h00 – 12h00":
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 3).setValue(1);
        break;
      case "12h00 – 17h00":
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 3).setValue(0);
        break;
      default:
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 3).setValue(label);
    }
  }); 
  
...
...
...
//Q19
  var labels = wsResponses.getRange(LastRow,21).getValues()[0];
  labels.forEach(function(label){
    switch(label) {    
      case "Definitely a morning type":
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 21).setValue(6);
        break;    
      case "Rather more a morning type than an evening type":
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 21).setValue(4);
        break;
      case "Rather more an evening type than a morning type":
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 21).setValue(2);
        break;
      case "Definitely an evening type":
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 21).setValue(0);
        break; 
      default:
        wsData.getRange(LastRow, 21).setValue(label);
    }
  });


  wsData.getRange(LastRow, 23).setValue(wsResponses.getRange(LastRow,22).getValues()[0]);
  wsData.getRange(LastRow, 24).setValue(wsResponses.getRange(LastRow,23).getValues()[0]);
  wsData.getRange(LastRow, 25).setValue(wsResponses.getRange(LastRow,24).getValues()[0]);

  var sum = 0;

  for (var i=3;i<=21;i=i+1)
  {
    sum = sum + parseInt(wsData.getRange(LastRow, i).getValues()[0]);
  };
  wsData.getRange(LastRow, 22).setValue(sum);
  return sum;  
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion or help.

Comment: Does this help: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en

Comment: may be have a look here https://www.inboxally.com/blog/why-is-gmail-blocking-my-emails-and-what-to-do-about-it

Comment: @Cooper; thanks, but none of that would justify why gmail blocks the mails.
@mike Steelson; thanks, but I am sending from gmail to gmail, so it is not an ISP setting.

Comment: I used to send myself programmatic messages to my other account and I had a lot of problems with  gmail blocking them so I just decided to take another route.  But heck if we really knew the answer we wouldn't be having this discussion.  So good luck hope you figure it out.